# tensoring invertible sheaf by function field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be an integral scheme with function field $K$. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$, and let $\mathcal{L}_K = \mathcal{L} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} K$, where $K$ is the constant sheaf on $X$ with value $K$.

Locally $\mathcal{L}_K|_U \simeq K|_U$, but do we have a global isomorphism 
$\mathcal{L}_K \cong K$?

Also, is $H^1(X, \mathcal{L}_K)=0$? Assume $X$ is separated and whatever else is needed for Cech cohomology to compute sheaf cohomomology.

Comment: Locally constant sheaves on irreducible schemes are constant. To see this, note that the generic point of your scheme is in every nonempty open. So the answer to your first question is yes.

Comment: For 2) Constant sheaves on an irreducible topological space are flasque.